# gRaphael Js: where can I find tutorials to produce data charts (pie, bar, etc)

Tags: javascript, graphael

Where can I find tutorials to produce data representations on the web with gRaphael? There seem to be no documentation on line.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I really would recommend against graphael just from personal experience.  I looked at it and got stuck several times during my implementation (ex, simple things like axis labels require hacks like setting text at specific spots), and the physical x-axis scaling/ticks that is visible (at least for bar charts that I've tried) don't seem related to the data, as if there is some internal axis that you can't see.  I could not find a single graph example that actually had even the minimum # of components a professional graph has (labels, legends, etc), so for me it's just a prettier 'sparklines'.  All in all, a lot more trouble than it's worth, plus any documentation you find will be minimal at best.

I would look into jquery options (great documentation and easy browser support for js)

1. highcharts is #1 if it's for personal
   use, very beautiful, interactive,
   and easy to use
2. flot, nice looking though not as
   interactive or as many options
3. jqplot, inspired by flot. this is my
   current choice. there's a huge
   amount of stuff you can do with
   this. interactive and professional
   looking, looks like a good sub for highcharts if the licensing fee is too much.

Flash charts (beautiful but flash is a no-no these days):

1. Open flash charts - It's not too bad
   to implement and I used it before I
   decided to switch to jqplot. Very
   nice looking charts, but my graphs
   needed to grab data from the server
   more dynamically, and I decided js
   was a better option to do it.
2. Amcharts - easily make good looking
   graphs via XML data.

Comment: HightCharts is nice, but it is not free for commercial websites

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be that many beginner tutorials, but here's a couple of reasonably introductory text with examples:

http://www.treutech.com/42/visualizing-data-jqplot-graphael, 
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/graphael-javascript-graphs, 
http://blog.jeremi.info/entry/creating-a-chart-with-raphael-js-from-a-google-spreadsheet